# Using python 2 & 3 next to each other (with eclipse if that matters)

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, python-3.x

Well this is quite the annoyance right now. I personally work in python 3, however a lot of university stuff is written in python 2.x... And I have to run that code too without constantly spending hours, if not days on debugging this.

So (using eclipse), is there an easy way to state: "hey I don't wish you to use the default compiler, I wish to use compiler XYZ". Or even better: is there a way python can detect this automatically?

Especially the print statement keeps bugging up at the most silly places.

Comment: you can install python2 next to python3 and use it to run your university stuff using `python2 myscript.py`

Comment: You could try converting the university stuff with `2to3`.

Comment: Continuing from @jonrsharpe, [This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) is the link to it

Comment: @njzk2 hmm any chance you (or someone else) knows where in the settings of eclipse this can be changed so it compiles correctly? Also it opens (again only with print, but that thing is everywhere) another can'o'worms. My own libraries suddenly report dozens of errors). I'm currently once again changing all occurrences.

Comment: Check this answer:

[Using different versions of python for different projects in Eclipse][http://stackoverflow.com/a/545880/4389243]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using different versions of python for different projects in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543466/using-different-versions-of-python-for-different-projects-in-eclipse)