# Eclipse imports wrong version of pandas in pydev environment

Tags: python, eclipse, pandas

I'd like to know why Eclipse debug environment is linking to pandas 0.14 yet the terminal (and virtual env) links to pandas 0.17.

I am using Eclipse on linux (ubuntu):

```
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200
```

The simple test program is

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
print ("DEBUG python version: ", sys.version)
print ("DEBUG main pd veriosn: ", pd.__version__)
```

I activate venv/py27/bin/activate and the command line output is

```
('DEBUG python version: ', '2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) \n[GCC 4.8.2]')
('DEBUG main pd veriosn: ', u'0.17.0')
```

When I run within Eclipse with PyDev interpreter pointed to the venv/py27/bin/python2.7  the output is

```
('DEBUG python version: ', '2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) \n[GCC 4.8.2]')
('DEBUG main pd veriosn: ', '0.14.1')
```

The pandas version is different inside of eclipse.

When I go to the myproject.properties.PyDev-Interpreter/Grammer it shows py27 which was configured.

When I go the eclipse 'Run As',RunConfiguration it shows 'Default Interpreter' that results in command line below.   The 1st line of PYTHONPATH is not in the project configuration.

```
/top/venv/myproject/bin/python2.7
-u
/top/myproject/src/tests/test_pandas.py

The PYTHONPATH that will be used is:

/home/rojasfr/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.5.0_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508182223/pysrc/pydev_sitecustomize:
/top/myproject:
/top/myproject/src:
/top/venv/myproject/lib/python2.7:
/top/venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:
/usr/lib/python2.7:
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:
/top/venv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/a/545880/1240268 ?

Comment: Simliar.   The link clarifies that I should use Run Configuration to set interpreter -ok so I will stick with Run Configuration.

Comment: I will stick with Run Configuration.   Yet, (see end of my description above).. the interpreter in Run Configuration has extra path in PYTHONPATH... I tried to rename $HOME/.eclipse but seems to have corrupted workspace even when I rename it back.    Needing to recover.

Comment: IIUC Picking the interpretter is more powerful than picking the PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I agree. But I believe eclipse installation was not done correctly.  So I have tried to uninstall/purge eclipse... and reinstall several times.  
I am using https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php?show_instructions=TRUE 
When I use sudo /opt/eclipse-installer/eclipse-inst it installs and I am able to Launch OK... 
But I exit eclipse (running under sudo) ... then I try running from my $HOME -->  /opt/eclipse/jee-mars/eclipse/eclipse
but it fails with message in pop-up [The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.[

Comment: Message from command line is : 
../../../../root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

** (eclipse:2889): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. after reinstalling eclipse several times... it seems it is NOT eclipse... it is functioning correctly.   Setting/picking the interpreter within Run Configuration (or Debug Configuration) is the way to go.

The root problem was complicated by the virtualenv failure (see b). 
a) my project requirements.txt referenced pandas 0.14.1 -- this took a long time to determine because of the following issue.    But the eclipse was pointing the interpreter what was installed using virtualenv... so it was performing correctly.

b) the remaining question is why the activate of the virtualenv 'venv27' with pandas 0.14 behaved wacky... ie. the PROMPT reflected that it had been activated.   But the 'which python' pointed to /usr/bin/python (after activation).    So somehow the venv27 was corrupted... took a while to determine by using the eclipse "command" description.

I changed the requirements.txt to point to pandas 0.17 and rebuilt the virtualenv 'venv27'.  Worked like it should.

Net this is now fixed.   Plenty of user error... but learned a lot.